# how i can calculate the adjacent and opposite of this matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, enumerate

**i have this matrix**

```py
Matrix = [[0., 15., 19., 18., 17.],
     [15., 0., 14., 12., 23.],
     [19., 14.,  0., 14., 21.],
     [18., 12., 14., 0., 14.],
     [17., 23., 21., 14.,  0.]]
```

**and i cut it to this by this code**

```py
c = [item[:index+1] for index, item in enumerate(Matrix[1:])]
c
```

**it show that**

```py
[array([15.]),
 array([19., 14.]),
 array([18., 12., 14.]),
 array([17., 23., 21., 14.])]
```

**and i want to calculate the adjacent and the opposite of this matrix example:**
**15+19+18+17 and 19+14+12+23 and 18+12+14+21 and 17 23 21 14**
**How i can  do that**

**i tried this to append all data and work on it but he show nothing**

```py
arr=[]
for item,data in enumerate(c):
          for item2,data2 in enumerate(data):
                    arr.append(data2)
                    print(item,item2,data2)

print(arr)
```

**and i try the code below and he print the diagonal **

```py
for item,data in enumerate(c):
          print(data[item:item+1])
```

**and i try this and it show**

```py
for item,data in enumerate(c):
    print(item, data[0:1], data[1:2],data[2:3],data[3:4])
```

```py
0 [15.] [] [] []
1 [19.] [14.] [] []
2 [18.] [12.] [14.] []
3 [17.] [23.] [21.] [14.]
```

**so i realized that i can iterate just on columns not on row is there are a method method to solve it?**
**This is example that i want to implement to better understand, here i want to calculate the summation of these vector**
[image: this example that i want to implement]

Comment: This is useful in algorithm of neighbor joining that I want to implement

Comment: If you share an output you expect, it would be easier to help you. Since you added `numpy` tag, it's recommended to replace  `for` loops with more efficient `numpy` methods. It looks like you're looking for methods like [`np.triu(Matrix)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html#numpy.triu) or [`np.tril(Matrix)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tril.html) but you need to be more clear about what you expect.

Comment: The example that I was gift  is the output to how to calculate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to calculate sum of rows of 'symmetrised' submatrix. I'll explain step by step.

At first, create a copy of submatrix:

```
>>> arr = Matrix[1:,:-1].copy()
>>> arr
array([[15.,  0., 14., 12.],
       [19., 14.,  0., 14.],
       [18., 12., 14.,  0.],
       [17., 23., 21., 14.]])
```

Then find a way to fill right upper triangle with values of left lower triangle. You could find both indices of left lower triangle and indices right upper triangle and use [advanced indexing](https://www.pythonlikeyoumeanit.com/Module3_IntroducingNumpy/AdvancedIndexing.html) to modify values of `arr`:

```
>>> idx = np.triu_indices(len(arr), 1) #indices of right upper triangle
>>> arr[idx] = arr.T[idx] #use advanced indexing to modify values
>>> arr
array([[15., 19., 18., 17.],
       [19., 14., 12., 23.],
       [18., 12., 14., 21.],
       [17., 23., 21., 14.]])
```

For better understanding of indexing you could also try to take a look at indices like you did in your double `for` looping:

```
>>> np.transpose(idx)
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 3],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [2, 3]])
```

Finally, calculate sums of rows:

```
>>> arr.sum(axis=0)
array([69., 68., 65., 75.]) #15+19+18+17, 19+14+12+23, 18+12+14+21 and 17+23+21+14
```